# What is the xtensor equivalent of pandas `groupby`?

Tags: c++, pandas, dataframe, xtensor

What is the C++ xtensor library equivalent of pandas `groupby`? Or, how can I easily group a dataframe with C++ xtensor library?

Answer (score 1):

xtensor does what numpy does for python.  The functionality in pandas is not replicated in xtensor.

Have you looked at [boost.python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python?action=show&redirect=BoostPython) as a method of binding the functionality together.  This will allow you to get the c++ datastructures into the python framework and use the pandas groupby there.

Comment: Actually I am not writing a python extension. I just need a C++ library that allows me to group data and do other common pandas operations. I already wrote a quite decent [library for that]( https://github.com/Eleobert/duf/blob/master/duf.hpp), but xtensor also seemed interesting.

Comment: But  `groupby` operation needs labels for columns, which xtensor (nor numpy) provides.